# Mysql optimization and explode

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that displays the top 10 most drawn pairs of numbers from the whole
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQrpB.jpg)

```
select 
    p, count(p) as frequency
from
    (SELECT 
         id, 
         CASE power1 <= power2 WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(power1,"-",power2) ELSE CONCAT(power2,"-",power1) 
         END p 
     FROM power 
     UNION
     SELECT 
         id, 
         CASE power1<=power3 WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(power1,"-",power3) ELSE CONCAT(power3,"-",power1) END p 
     FROM power 
     UNION
     SELECT 
         id, 
         CASE power1<=power4 WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(power1,"-",power4) ELSE CONCAT(power4,"-",power1) END p 
     FROM power 
     UNION
     ...............................................
     SELECT 
         id, 
         CASE power19<=power20 WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(power19,"-",power20) ELSE CONCAT(power20,"-",power19) 
         END p 
     FROM power) as b
group by 
    p
order by 
    frequency desc, p asc
limit
    0, 10
```

1. How can I impose a limit to take just the first 100 lines in descending order by ID? The query would be like this:

   ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,100

   But I haven't been able to adapt it for the above.
2. Could the code be optimized more than that?
3. power1, Power2 are values from tables.... would it work if i would have a string like 3,4,5,6 and then explode "," and after that power1 becomes 3, power2 to become 4, etc?

I mean the table format to look something like this :

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsfKm.png)

LATER EDIT :

I have table like this :

Table: `data`

```
+----+----+-----+
| id | nr | set | 
+----+----+-----+
|  1 | 52 |   1 | 
|  2 | 47 |   1 | 
|  3 |  4 |   1 | 
|  4 |  3 |   1 | 
|  5 | 77 |   1 | 
|  6 | 71 |   1 | 
|  7 |  6 |   1 | 
|  8 | 41 |   1 | 
|  9 | 15 |   1 | 
| 10 | 79 |   1 | 
| 11 | 35 |   2 | 
| 12 | 50 |   2 | 
| 13 | 16 |   2 | 
| 14 |  1 |   2 | 
| 15 | 32 |   2 | 
| 16 | 77 |   2 | 
| 17 | 30 |   2 | 
| 18 |  7 |   2 | 
| 19 | 20 |   2 | 
| 20 | 28 |   2 | 
| .. | .. | ... | 
+----+----+-----+
```

I have like 34360 id

And the following query :

```
SELECT 
    `n1`.`nr` AS `num_1`,
    `n2`.`nr` AS `num_2`,
    COUNT(1) AS `total`

FROM (select * from data ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,1000) AS `n1`

JOIN `data` AS `n2` 
    ON `n1`.`set` = `n2`.`set` AND `n1`.`nr` < `n2`.`nr`

GROUP BY `n1`.`nr`, `n2`.`nr`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

And is working fine !

I would like to know how i can find out the pairs of numbers that have not been drawn together for the longest time. Per example:

- 1,42 (together, as a pair) has not been drawn for 24 draws
- 32,45-as a pair as well-has not been drawn for 22 draws
- etc

Comment: On the face of it, there's so much wrong here, I'm not sure where to begin. But normalisation mmight be a good place to start.

Comment: Normalization .... like this ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/OsfKm.png

Comment: No. That is the opposite of normalization.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

Un-normalised:

```
id power1 power2 power3 power4
 1      4      9     10     16
 2      6     12     15     19
 3      2      4      6      7
 4      3      8     15     17
 5      2     10     11     14
 6      4     10     12     19
 7      1      4      9     11
```

Normalised:

```
 id power value
  1     1     4    
  1     2     9    
  1     3    10    
  1     4    16
  2     1     6     
  2     2    12    
  2     3    15
  2     4    19
  3     1     2     
  3     2     4     
  3     3     6     
  3     4     7
  4     1     3     
  4     2     8     
  4     3    15    
  4     4    17
  5     1     2     
  5     2    10    
  5     3    11    
  5     4    14
  6     1     4     
  6     2    10    
  6     3    12    
  6     4    19
  7     1     1     
  7     2     4     
  7     3     9     
  7     4    11
```

So...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,power INT NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,power)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,4),(1,2,9),(1,3,10),(1,4,16),
(2,1,6),(2,2,12),(2,3,15),(2,4,19),
(3,1,2),(3,2,4),(3,3,6),(3,4,7),
(4,1,3),(4,2,8),(4,3,15),(4,4,17),
(5,1,2),(5,2,10),(5,3,11),(5,4,14),
(6,1,4),(6,2,10),(6,3,12),(6,4,19),
(7,1,1),(7,2,4),(7,3,9),(7,4,11);

SELECT LEAST(x.value,y.value)a -- LEAST/GREATEST is only necessary in the event that 
     , GREATEST(x.value,y.value) b -- power1 value may be greater than powerN value
     , COUNT(*) freq 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.power < x.power 
 GROUP 
    BY LEAST(x.value, y.value) -- again only necessary if using LEAST/GREATEST above
     , GREATEST(x.value,y.value) 
 ORDER 
    BY freq DESC
     , a
     , b;
+----+----+------+
| a  | b  | freq |
+----+----+------+
|  4 |  9 |    2 |
|  4 | 10 |    2 |
| 12 | 19 |    2 |
|  1 |  4 |    1 |
|  1 |  9 |    1 |
|  1 | 11 |    1 |
|  2 |  4 |    1 |
|  2 |  6 |    1 |
|  2 |  7 |    1 |
|  2 | 10 |    1 |
|  2 | 11 |    1 |
|  2 | 14 |    1 |
|  3 |  8 |    1 |
|  3 | 15 |    1 |
|  3 | 17 |    1 |
|  4 |  6 |    1 |
|  4 |  7 |    1 |
|  4 | 11 |    1 |
|  4 | 12 |    1 |
|  4 | 16 |    1 |
|  4 | 19 |    1 |
|  6 |  7 |    1 |
|  6 | 12 |    1 |
|  6 | 15 |    1 |
|  6 | 19 |    1 |
|  8 | 15 |    1 |
|  8 | 17 |    1 |
|  9 | 10 |    1 |
|  9 | 11 |    1 |
|  9 | 16 |    1 |
| 10 | 11 |    1 |
| 10 | 12 |    1 |
| 10 | 14 |    1 |
| 10 | 16 |    1 |
| 10 | 19 |    1 |
| 11 | 14 |    1 |
| 12 | 15 |    1 |
| 15 | 17 |    1 |
| 15 | 19 |    1 |
+----+----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, i can do that. But i don't know how to adapt for my query.

Comment: @Xander Again, see above.

Comment: a good answer. Deserves a sprinkle of points imho. To those willing to roll up their sleeves and do it right

Answer (score 0):

While I fully agree with @Strawberry about normalising your data, the following is an example of how to possibly do it with your current data structure (not tested).

```
SELECT CASE a.power_val <= b.power_val WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(a.power_val,"-",b.power_val) ELSE CONCAT(b.power_val,"-",a.power_val) END p, 
        COUNT(a.id) as frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT id,1 AS power_col, power1 AS power_val FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,2, power2 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,3, power3 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,4, power4 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,5, power5 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,6, power6 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,7, power7 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,8, power8 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,9, power9 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,10, power10 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,11, power11 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,12, power12 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,13, power13 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,14, power14 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,15, power15 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,16, power16 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,17, power17 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,18, power18 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,19, power19 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,20, power20 FROM power 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 2000
) a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, 1 AS power_col, power1 AS power_val FROM power UNION
    SELECT id, 2, power2 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,3, power3 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,4, power4 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,5, power5 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,6, power6 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,7, power7 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,8, power8 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,9, power9 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,10, power10 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,11, power11 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,12, power12 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,13, power13 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,14, power14 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,15, power15 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,16, power16 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,17, power17 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,18, power18 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,19, power19 FROM power UNION
    SELECT id,20, power20 FROM power 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 2000
) b
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.power_col != b.power_col
GROUP BY p
ORDER BY frequency DESC, p ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Note using normalised data structures would likely be far quicker.

EDIT

Think something like the following might give you what you need.

The big sub query is to get every possible combination (idea is to also cope with pairs that have never been used), with the first number being smaller than the 2nd just for consistency. This is then joined against the tables of data to get the matching numbers and the respective id fields. Then uses MIN to get the smallest id:-

```
SELECT all_combo.num_1, 
        all_combo.num_2, 
        MIN(d1.id)
FROM
(
    SELECT     sub0.nr AS num_1,
                sub1.nr AS num_2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT nr
        FROM data
    ) sub0
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT nr
        FROM data
    ) sub1
    WHERE sub0.nr < sub1.nr
) all_combo
LEFT OUTER JOIN data d1 ON all_combo.num_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN data d2 ON all_combo.num_2 AND d1.set = d2.set
GROUP BY all_combo.num_1, 
        all_combo.num_2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be better for me to apply on this format table. But your code it doesnt work and i can't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Done a few minor changes. Have you got some example data and the results you would expect from it?

Comment: Its woking now. I have like 9000 rows in my table. How can i search on entire table ? And for exemple how can i search only on last 100 ID for exemple. From your exemple i dont understand exactly what is LIMIT 2000. –

Comment: The LIMIT 2000 is getting for the last 100 id on the table (100 id x 20 columns = 2000).

Comment: No problem, but I really would recommend that you follow the advice of @Strawberry and normalise your database design. It will make things like this far easier, and also make it a lot easier when you need to change from 20 powers to (say) 30 powers.

Comment: I understand. I had normalized my table. But with his exemple i cant rewrite code for 3/3 numbers ... so not pairs (2/2) ... because i dont know. Can you give me a hint or exemple ? I need for 3/3, 4/4, 5/5 and 6/6. My real database have 20 power numbers, not only 4 like my exemple. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a small bit of sample data for 3x3 and what you want to be output as I am not certain on what you require.

Comment: I had edit my first post. I really really need some help. It against the forum rules to write that i need a good freelancer SQL ? I really need that queries and i i will pay for them.

Comment: @Xander - added some (untested) SQL that might help.

Comment: Probably down to the amount of data. Can you set up a table containing the possible values of nr? But with lots of combinations the amount of data ramps up rapidly.

Comment: Yes, i can make a table containing all possible combinations, i know there are many, but i really need to know how it can be done.
 Could you please tell me what structure does the table has to have? And if you want of course, tell me how can i contact you in private.
 I need a lot more done and i still didn't find the right man to pay him for this work.

Comment: Afraid I have too much on to do extra work beyond the odd bit of help on here. The table I meant is one of all the possible values. To get all the combinations that table can just be joined against itself. If you want combinations of 3 (or more) just join it against itself again. If this is indexed the joins should be acceptable. Problem is the numbers ramp up; if you have 100 possible values to give a combination of 3 values you have ~1000000 possible combinations, each to be checked against multiple sets.